# Proving a transfer function is proper or not

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I'm trying to prove (not just show) whether the following transfer function is proper or not
$$
G(s) = \frac{1}{1+se^{-s}}
$$

A transfer function $G(s)$ is said to be proper if there is $\alpha \geq 0$ such that
$$\sup_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}\left\Vert G(s)\right\Vert<\infty$$
where $\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}:=\left\{ \text{Re}\left(s\right)>\alpha\right\} $

Thanks

Edit:

The $\left\Vert .\right\Vert$  operator is used (rather than $\left| .\right|$) because this definition holds for a [MIMO transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function_matrix) as well.

So far I've arrived at
$$\sup_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}\left\Vert \frac{1}{1+se^{-s}}\right\Vert =\inf_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}\left|1+se^{-s}\right|\underset{s=\sigma+j\omega}{=}\inf_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}\left|1+\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)e^{-\sigma-j\omega}\right|$$

if I use the triangle inequality I have
$$\inf_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}\left|1+\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)e^{-\sigma-j\omega}\right|\leq\inf_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}1+\left|\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)e^{-\sigma-j\omega}\right|=\inf_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}1+\left|\sigma+j\omega\right|\left|e^{-\sigma}\right|{\left|e^{-j\omega}\right|}=\left(\inf_{s\in\mathbb{C}_{\alpha}}1+\left|\sigma+j\omega\right|\left|e^{-\sigma}\right|\right)_{\omega\to\infty}=\infty$$

which is not very helpful

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for including the definition of "proper transfer function".  You should be able to write out an expression for $||G(s)||$ although given the problem setup, I suspect you meant to write $|G(s)|$, the absolute value of a complex number.

Comment: I think your edit greatly improve the Question and brought you close to the solution, so I've upvoted it.  Note that in your first rewriting you have $$\sup_{s\in C_\alpha} |\frac{1}{1+se^{-s}}| = \inf_{s\in C_\alpha} |1+se^{-s}|$$ But this omits inverting the infimum on the right hand side, and I suspect that is why you reached a "not very helpful" conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Applying your definition of a proper transfer function to rational transfer functions (i.e. transfer functions with only polynomial expressions in $s$ for the numerator and denominator) is equivalent to that the order of the numerator polynomial should be equal or less than the order of the denominator polynomial and that the denominator only has roots (i.e. poles) with negative real part. Usually, I encounter the [definition of proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_transfer_function) without the constraints on the poles and thus only with the constraint on the order of the numerator.

The constraint on the order of the numerator would ensure that $\|G(s)\|<\infty$ when $|s|\to\infty$. This can be shown to be the case for your transfer function. Now it only has to be checked if all poles of your transfer function are stable, for which we need to solve

$$
1+s\,e^{-s}=0. \tag{1}
$$

It can be shown that the [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bs*exp%28-s%29%3D0) to $(1)$ are $s=-W_n(1)$, with $W_n(x)$ the n$^\text{th}$ [Lambert W-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html). However, $Re(-W_1(1))=1.5339>0$ which would imply at least one unstable pole with positive real part and thus not proper.

---

It would also be possible to derive that your transfer function is unstable (at least one pole with positive real part) by considering that your transfer can also be obtained by applying unit negative feedback to $s\,e^{-s}$ (your transfer function would be the associated closed loop sensitivity transfer function). Namely, from the Nyquist plot of $s\,e^{-s}$, using the Nyquist stability criterion, it would follow that the closed loop is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be strictly proper because the delay part has no excess of poles or zeros, so the s multiplying it must make the complete transfer function tend to zero at infinity. But I'll leave it for you try other forms of verifying the limits formally.

Comment: Be wary of posting "answers" that are substantially shorter and less mathematically reasoned than the Question to which they respond.  You could have posted this as a Comment, esp. omitting the "I'll leave it for you [to] try" qualification.  In the alternative you can revise your Answer to give a reasonably definitive solution.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your comment and I agree with you. And, I think this is the appropriate level of detail of an answer to the question. It is sufficient to figure out the details.